# Vue.js + Typescript: How to set @Prop type to string array?

Tags: typescript, vue.js, vuejs2, typescript-typings, typescript-generics

What's the correct way to set the `type` attribute of the `@Prop` decorator to `Array<string>`? Is it even possible?

I'm only able to set it to `Array` without `string` like so:

```
<script lang="ts">
import { Component, Prop, Vue } from 'vue-property-decorator';

@Component
export default class MyComponent extends Vue {
  @Prop({ type: Array, default: [] }) private readonly myProperty!: string[];
}
</script>
```

When I try to change it to `Array<string>` or even `string[]` I receive the following error:

```
Argument of type '{ type: boolean; default: never[]; }' is not assignable 
to parameter of type 'PropOptions<any> | Constructor | Constructor[] | undefined'.

Types of property 'type' are incompatible. Type 'boolean' is not assignable to type 
'(new (...args: string[]) => Function) | (() => any) | (new (...args: never[]) => any) | Prop<any>[] | undefined'.
```

This error message confuses me even more: why is the type now recognised as `boolean`?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Adding the type assertion `as PropType<string[]>` helps in this case:

```
<script lang="ts">
import { PropType } from "vue"
import { Component, Prop, Vue } from 'vue-property-decorator';

@Component
export default class MyComponent extends Vue {
  @Prop({
    type: Array as PropType<string[]>, // use PropType
    default: () => [] // use a factory function
  }) private readonly myProperty!: string[];
}
</script>
```

Source: [docs](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/typescript.html#Annotating-Props) regarding `@Prop` annotation.

Also note that default `Array`s and `Object`s should always be returned from factory functions ([source](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-props.html#Prop-Validation)). This avoids (accidentally) sharing a property among several component instances.